# Is https://www.flightsticketcorp.com a reliable website to book air tickets?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, online-resources, bookings

I found that this website (www.flightsticketcorp.com) provides the cheapest flight details. I would like to know how reliable this site is for flight booking?

Is there anyone who has booked flights using this website?

Comment: The website isn't written by a native English speaker. For me that raises concerns about the quality of the rest of their product. But I have never used this site or heard of it before.

Comment: It also has non-US phone numbers, and doesn't post full prices as required by DOT guidelines.

Comment: LOL I ran https://www.flightsticketcorp.com/about-us/management through Google Image search, these are some stock images of whatever website CMS, http://gulfstariq.com/projects2.php here they are with full lorem ipsum :D or here http://www.kaitomould.com/kaito-team/ with Chinese Lorem Ipsum (both texts are the same including name).

Answer (score 11):

You should've just Googled their URL. This raises enough red flags<sup>*</sup> to avoid them:

- [TripAdvisor post 10 June 2017](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g1-i10702-k10557879-Flightsticketcorp-Air_Travel.html)
- [Trustpilot.com review going back all 2017](https://www.trustpilot.com/review/cheapflightscorp.com)
- [Quora question March 2017](https://www.quora.com/Has-anyone-booked-flight-tickets-on-https-www-cheapflightscorp-com)

Note that they operate under many more domain names.

<sup>Many negative remarks are not backed up with proof, that's why I 'only' use the term *red flag*.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I have had a very bad experience, there is an extra cost will be charged after taking your initial payment. When you want a refund, it takes half a year. I am still waiting for my refund and I initiated it in June. Even I contacted their customer services or complaint services, it is not working.

Answer (score -1):

I have a problem with this website, flightsticketcorp.com.
I called my Bank to stop my credit card paying for this ticket.
I have seen a lot of comments ilke [this](https://www.tripadvisor.ca/ShowTopic-g1-i10702-k10557879-Flightsticketcorp-Air_Travel.html):

> Hi there. These guys are a total scam. I just got caught!
>
> They claim to offer a 2-part payment system. However, they don't make it clear before or during the booking process. You only discover this after you pay and is highlighted in the conformation email.
>
> So, the price you think your are paying is only 55% of the total fee. AFTER you pay the 55% you receive an email stating you need to pay the 45% balance. The booking system and all the details right up to paying appeared legitimate. Paid my USD2579.00 quoted. After CC payment confirmed emails come through showing payment was 55% (USD2579) and need to pay 45% balance (USD211) 'once i have confirmed all details are correct. Total USD4690.00 business for a Hong Kong - Glasgow business class airfare.
>
> They also state on their website you can receive a full 100% refund within 12 hours of booking. I emailed immediately within minutes after receiving the confirmation email to cancel the booking. I received a reply the day after from Vicky.ng@flightsticketcorp.com i had many options to modify my booking, take a cheaper economy flight or cancel with charges. I immediately called the various phone numbers noted on their website; Hong Kong, Australia, UK. None of the phone numbers are answered nor have voicemail or an answering service.
>
> I have now called my CC bank to report this company.
>
> I'll go back to booking direct online with the airlines....

Be careful, don't use this web site!